# Configuring Jenkins with Bitbucket URL

Tags: java, git, maven, configuration, jenkins

I am trying to configure a maven job to run in jenkins - I have been getting the following error for some time now (with other variations dependant on what I change)

> Failed to connect to repository : Failed to connect to
>   https://bitbucket.org/rickilambert/secondstoryuk/Core.git using
>   credentials  (status = 404)

I have tried many variations of connection URL inclusive of the 2 most recommended on stack overflow

```
https://<user>:<pass>@bitbucket.org/<user>/<project>.git 

https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project>.git
```

Both to no avail - has anyone come across an error like this before or indeed have any idea how to fix it? For reference Jenkins is running the GIT plugin version 2.2.2

Thanks

Comment: A 404 error is pretty explicit, it means that the URL doesn't exist - I got a 404 when I tried to access through a browser as well.  I think the issue is probably with the fact that your BitBucket repo is private - you could try setting up SSH access and see if that helps.  https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Answer (score 0):

404 error means the url does not exist.

You should double check if the url is valid or not.